# UICollectionViewCell XIB: installed checkbox for size class not working

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I want to configure my collection view cell subclass to display different labels for iPhone portrait/landscape. iPhone landscape rules also applied for iPad. So I have `installed` checkboxes for set of size classes in my XIB file. But it is not working on iPad. On iPhone it is working only after second change of device orientation. Is it iOS bug?

[image]